# Check out with SVN client from GIT repository

Tags: git, svn, github

I am migrating a project from svn to git. My plan is to have a central repository on a private server in our office with gogs or webdav.

Today i have read about a feature, github provides. If you have a repository on github, you can check out a branch with an svn client. Then you can edit your files locally and push it back to the repository on github with your svn client. ([Github support for subversion clients](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/))

This would be very handy because some of the project members have only TortoiseSVN installed and can't switch to TortoiseGIT. This is, because TortoiseGIT needs admin permissions to install the client.

These project members will only edit some Markdown and config files or small bugfixes. So the limitations of using an svn client aren't a big problem.

I have found many resources about how to do it the other way around (git client, svn server), but I can't find anything about how to implement a feature like github has.

Can anyone give me some hints where to start?

I would prefer existing solutions if its free for commercial use, but it would be also ok if some coding is necessary.

Comment: TortoiseGIT is a horrible tool and I strongly recommend you to avoid it.

Comment: Why? Can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 2):

You can start from this

http://www.subgit.com/

or

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532077-Version-Control-with-Git-and-SVN

Or use the private GitHub repos

Or give some portable git client to your TortoiseSVN users.

Comment: ... and don't use SmartGit at all

Comment: @Lazy Badger  Why?